# How to generate Package.xml file in lightning web component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have created three lightning web components and four apex class using Visual Studio code. Now Client wants to create package.xml with all components, it should also include LWC as well. I tried by using workbench by adding Force.com Migration Tool Package Creator Extension to chrome browser and below is the package.xml file created:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

<types>

<members>salesOrders</members>

<members>orderList</members>

<members>paginatorBottom</members>

<name>LightningComponentBundle</name>

</types>

<version>34.0</version>

</Package>
```

It's not included LWC.So what is the best way to achieve this Please suggest? What step I should follow to create the package.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit here is the API version.

```
<version>45.0</version>
```

use 45 or 46 you should be able to retrieve it.

Comment: I am not able to edit xml file in workbench.

Comment: update the file in the text editor and again upload it

Comment: When i edit xml in text editor and load XML in workbench its remain same.Is there any solution for it?

Comment: create a new copy of it.

Comment: I did it but  it not work.

Comment: try to clear cookies of your browser or maybe try to open in incognito mode.